How is coherence score calculated in Mallet?
I do understand how the diagnostics output shows the coherence values for each topic but my values range between -150 and -600 and other posts that I have seen where Mallet was used show coherence scores that seem to range between 0.0-1.0. Is there a command in Mallet (or any other way) to calculate coherence scores from values?

The value calculated by Mallet is as reported in the published Talley et al. paper from 2009. "Coherence" is a vague term that could refer to many functions. It has probably been reinvented in different ways many times. You should look for more details about what is being calculated.

Thank you @David. I am afraid I can't find the Talley paper you mentioned. Are you able to link it for me or give me its exact title?

Sorry, I was thinking of this one: https://aclanthology.org/D11-1024.Pdf
